# opendaylight: difference between features/features-X and features/odl-X

Tags: opendaylight

I am developing an application for nitrogen. When I ran maven to generate an archetype, I got directories like features/features-X and features/odl-X with pom.xml in each one. Presumably, I am supposed to put feature dependencies in these pom.xml files. What is the difference between these two directories? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The features-X directory aggregates all the project's features in a feature repository. The odl-* directories are the project's single features. A feature repository is registered with karaf via the feature:repo-add command or the featuresRepositories property in etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg. It makes all the project's features available to karaf so they can be installed via feature:install.